# Haskell. Feeding a program with parameters (pure way)

Tags: haskell, input, io

I'm interested in possible ways to supply parameters into my program. It is a physical simulation and I need to input temperature, number of steps and so on.

However I need these parameters to be pure so I can't use IO in any way. Hence at least part of my program have to be recompiled each time. What is the best method to achieve this?

As far as I remember xmonad uses the same technique.

**UPD** It seems Dyre does what I need. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dyre Shall try it.

**UPD2** Dyre does a bit different thing.

Comment: So you are saying you want Input to be handled manually or by a separate program that modifies the code? And then you don't want any output? Or you do want output...you just don't want input? The type of main is IO(). So you have to have IO somewhere in your code....

Comment: Why can't these things be passed in as parameters to the functions that needs them?  And then a `getArgs` in main to get the command line arguments?

Comment: If you can't use IO in any way, how are you outputting the results of the simulation?

Comment: @dave4420 If his computer gets hot, it worked.  If it stays cool there must have been an error.

Comment: 2augustss I don't want to pass them as parameters as it would be to bulky --- in that case all functions would require one extra parameter. And I'm not sure this would be as efficient as having just several global functions (representing parameters).

Comment: @dave4420 I meant no IO for input

Comment: @Yrogirg, you're going to have to give us some indication on how you actually plan on getting the values for the parameters. Any way besides explicit declaration will result in having to dip into IO. Like reading from a file, getArgs, etc. In short, how do you actually plan on getting the program your parameter values?

Comment: @Yrogirg, you can post your answer as an answer instead of editing the question. You can accept it too! This is actually the preferred way rather than leaving the question without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

From a comment on the question:

> I don't want to pass them as parameters as it would be to bulky --- in that case all functions would require one extra parameter. And I'm not sure this would be as efficient as having just several global functions (representing parameters).

There are some misconceptions implicit here that need to be examined.

First, the well-known one: **If you're not sure about efficiency, don't optimize yet!** Write the program in a way that's sensible first, then profile it if needed to improve speed. Preemptive optimization is only a good idea when you know it will reduce the time or space complexity of your algorithm, or if it will significantly reduce constant factors in a very computation-intensive part of the program. Neither is the case here.

Second, **functions are supposed to take as many parameters as they need**. This sounds like a tautology, and it nearly is, but the point is that it makes no sense to reduce the number of arguments passed to a function that actually uses those arguments. If it *doesn't* actually use some arguments, remove those; if groups of arguments are used together in subexpressions, extract those as separate functions and pass in the result instead; if a bunch of arguments are passed around together to multiple functions, bundle them in a record type and pass that as a single argument; but don't try to eliminate parameters for the sake of eliminating them. That makes no sense!

Furthermore, from the question itself:

> However I need these parameters to be pure so I can't use IO in any way. Hence at least part of my program have to be recompiled each time.

Pure parameters aren't. They're constant values. You may define them elsewhere in the source code, but after compilation they're fixed and immutable. If the program needs access to parameters that *do* change after compilation, that *has* to use I/O. That's practically the *definition* of I/O!

Keep in mind that even if you need to obtain values in an `IO` computation, all the actual logic can be done in a pure function, like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do x <- getParameter
          let r = lotsOfCalculations x
          print r
```

The function `lotsOfCalculations`, as well as anything else it uses, will be pure functions. The only use of `IO` is to get the parameters.

Also, to be more concise, note that the above code could also be written as `main = getParameter >>= print . lotsOfCalculations`.

Comment: It would be nice to mention `xmonad`-style configuration (automatic program self-recompilation with the given configuration `.hs` file), how it works and when it's needed, as it was explicitly mentioned in the question. I'm saying this because this is a counter-intuitive at first, but very powerful configuration technique, which people should use more!

Comment: @Rotsor: The answer to that would likely be "anyone who needs to ask probably doesn't need it". The question suggests a misunderstanding of how to do things the simple way; explaining how to do them the complicated way is counterproductive and misleading.

Comment: You are probably right that this is not really needed in this case, but that point of view is important and deserves explicit mentioning! I mean, when one asks "how to do it the complicated way?", the answer "here is a simple way to do it", strictly speaking, is not. :)

Comment: @Rotsor: Questions read strictly as asked often differ from the question whose answer is truly desired; literal interpretation is better left to the compiler. But yes, it wouldn't have hurt to explicitly mention and discourage such unnecessary approaches.

Comment: @Rotsor Do you know how does xmonad do it?

Comment: @Yrogirg, no, I can only guess... xmonad sources should tell the whole story though.

Answer (score 2):

Use a reader monad, for example [`Reader r`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Reader.html#g:2) from Control.Monad.Reader. Then run the computation using `runReader`.

You pass the simulation parameters to `runReader`, then the components of your simulation can access them using `ask` and `asks`.

(Note: this requires that you bundle up all the parameters into a single data type.)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're running this program inside the interpreter, you'll have to dip into IO at some point. Most likely through the main function, which is impure.

In any case, just design your functions as pure. In your impure functions, you can use the `Maybe` monad to purify values, then pass (or not pass in the case of Nothing) them into your pure functions.

Keep in mind, to get any sort of output from the program, it will need to run through an IO function, either explicitly (e.g. main function) or implicitly (the interpreter).

Answer (score 1):

Try using a closure,

```
doCalculation params input = inner input where
    inner = ... (references params variable)
    inner2 = ... (references params variable)
```

In general, in Haskell, when you try to violate purity, bad things happen. For example, wrapping a random number generator call in `unsafePerformIO` means you don't get random numbers, since it will start reusing the calculation (in unexpected ways).

Also, there's record types, so  you can create something like

```
data Params = Params { name :: String, speed :: Double }
```